# Ubuntu crontab doesn't find my script after many different ways of running it

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I've got an Ubuntu dedicated machine and I have to create a cronjob that runs my script at 3 am every day. When I try to make the cronjob it just gives me an error that the file couldn't be found, but it's directly there... I've tried to run it with `PATH=` in the crontab (commented 1st line) and without a path in the "command" part of the crontab.

Am I missing something?

The script is currently in `/root/`

Crontab: (don't mind the hour, testing purposes)
http://prntscr.com/ecivq0

Error in the mail:
http://prntscr.com/eciwkw

Comment: Are you sure its in /root and not /root/scripts?  I ask only because in one of your screen shots you reference /root/scripts.

Comment: It was in /root/scripts first but then i moved it to just /root to see if the folder is creating an issue. 
<http://prntscr.com/ecjbub>